# What benefit I will get to create an abstract class rather than the base class in CPP?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

In our project - C++, we have the generic module called "ContentCache". From this contentcache, we have derived the customer specific contentcache - for example - Airtel, TataSky. For example, the base contentCache has the method - create the database table, store the basic information. The other types of contentcache which has a relationship like airtel content cache is a type of contentcache. This airtel content cache is customized - overriden a few methods. However, the rest of it are the same. On a few products, we simply use the generic - contentCache. My question is do we need an abstract class - ContentCache - IcontentCache. Also, what is the good way - creating an abstract class or just create a generic base class. What advantage do we get with the IContentCache- i.e. abstract class. I am looking an answer from the design pattern point of view. Also, the programming point of view.

Answer (score 2):

usually you use an abstract class if you define some functionality which can only be used if some additional, unavailable information (or functionality), is needed for that class to work. The unavailable but required information is defined as abstract methods of the class, then derived classes provide that extra information (or functionality).

In your example, if you can usefully have a generic `ContentCache` then it doesn't need to be abstract. But you might have a design where a `ContentCache` cannot be instantiated without knowing the name of the specific customer. In this case you might define all of the cache functionality in the abstract base class and have an abstract method which provides the name of the customer. Then in the derived classes you provide the implementation which returns that customer name and the class then has everything it needs to create the cache.

Admittedly this is not a great example as you could just provide the customer name in the constructor of the class, but you mention that in the derived classes you 'override a few methods'. These methods might be candidates for being abstract if they provide functionality which cannot be determined without knowing the customer.

Comment: Another twist is that the contentCache is singleton. So, only one product can be active.

Comment: hmm.. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166430/singleton-inheritance) about singleton inheritance. Although I think in your particular instance you have already shown that you don't want an abstract base class as you have uses for the generic cache on its own.

Comment: no.. my question is whether to have an abstract class or not for such a case. Also, what are the advantages if any? I want my code to be extensible, and as generic as possible. That's why I am looking for a good pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract class is better than just a normal base class. From the design perspective when ever we design a base class , we know that there is going to be inheritance (virtual functions). So we try to collect the common functions in the base class which will mostly be over ride in the derived class. Abstract means hiding the actual implementations from the outside world.Our implementations are our wealth.So base class needs to only work as an interface kind of thing and it should not have any implementation.

1. Abstract classes are good for you when ever your derived classes are going to ALWAYS use their derived class function definition rathar than using the base class definition.
2. Normal base classes will be useful , if you are going to use the base class virtual function definition along with the derived class function definition. Normal base class it will be good for small inheritance levels.